# scala : better solution

Tags: performance, scala

QUESTION:
    We define super digit of an integer x using the following rules:

```
Iff x has only 1 digit, then its super digit is x.
Otherwise, the super digit of x is equal to the super digit of the digit-sum of x. Here, digit-sum of a number is defined as the sum of its digits.
For example, super digit of 9875 will be calculated as:

super-digit(9875) = super-digit(9+8+7+5) 
                  = super-digit(29) 
                  = super-digit(2+9)
                  = super-digit(11)
                  = super-digit(1+1)
                  = super-digit(2)
                  = 2.
You are given two numbers - n k. You have to calculate the super digit of P.

P is created when number n is concatenated k times. That is, if n = 123 and k = 3, then P = 123123123.

Input Format 
Input will contain two space separated integers, n and k.

Output Format

Output the super digit of P, where P is created as described above.

Constraint

1≤n<10100000
1≤k≤105
Sample Input

148 3
Sample Output

3
Explanation 
Here n = 148 and k = 3, so P = 148148148.

super-digit(P) = super-digit(148148148) 
               = super-digit(1+4+8+1+4+8+1+4+8)
               = super-digit(39)
               = super-digit(3+9)
               = super-digit(12)
               = super-digit(1+2)
               = super-digit(3)
               = 3.
```

I have written the following program to solve the above problem , but how to solve it even efficiently and is string operation efficient than math operation ??? and for few inputs it takes a long time for example

861568688536788 100000

```
object SuperDigit {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution
*/
    def generateString (no:String,re:BigInt , tot:BigInt , temp:String):String = {
      if(tot-1>re) generateString(no+temp,re+1,tot,temp)
      else no
    }
    def totalSum(no:List[Char]):BigInt = no match {
      case x::xs =>  x.asDigit+totalSum(xs)
      case Nil => '0'.asDigit


    }

    def tot(no:List[Char]):BigInt = no match {
      case _ if no.length == 1=> no.head.asDigit
      case no => tot(totalSum(no).toString.toList)

    }
    var list = readLine.split(" ");
    var one = list.head.toString();
    var two = BigInt(list(1));
    //println(generateString("148",0,3,"148"))
    println(tot(generateString(one,BigInt(0),two,one).toList))
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reduction is to realise that you do not have to concatenate the number considered as a string k times but rather can start with the number k * qs(n) (where qs is the function that maps a number to its sum of digits, i. e. qs(123) = 1+2+3). Here is a more functional programming stylish approach. I do not know whether it can be made faster than this.

```
object Solution {

  def qs(n: BigInt): BigInt = n.toString.foldLeft(BigInt(0))((n, ch) => n + (ch - '0').toInt)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val input = scala.io.Source.stdin.getLines

    val Array(n, k) = input.next.split(" ").map(BigInt(_))

    println(Stream.iterate(k * qs(n))(qs(_)).find(_ < 10).get)
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is the best solution thumbs up

Comment: There is a Coursera class by Martin Odersky called "Functional Programming in Scala" and a book by Runár with the same name published by manning (goes on sale regularly, on 22. Sept. you can use the promotional code dotd092214cc). Both of these will get you to intermediate level and then it is about applying it. You can then take a look at the sourcecodes of scalaz and shapeless to increase your skills.